# Two BoxLayouts Side by Side in Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, boxlayout

I have a BoxLayout in my frame with all my **main** buttons, and another BoxLayout with buttons for help and to exit the program. I don't know how to have these two side-by-side, and setting the location of the BoxLayouts does nothing.

This is how I want my frame to look:

[image: Frame Look]

And this is my code:

```
private static void contentGUI(Container pane)  {
    pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JButton task1 = new JButton(" > Advanced CPU Settings");
    pane.add(task1); 
    JButton task2 = new JButton(" > Advanced Memory Settings");
    pane.add(task2);
    JButton task3 = new JButton(" > Advanced GPU Settings");
    pane.add(task3);
    JButton task4 = new JButton(" > Advanced Case Fan Settings");
    pane.add(task4);

}

private static void toolTips() throws IOException, FontFormatException {
    JPanel toolTipPane = new JPanel();
    toolTipPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(toolTipPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JButton tip1 = new JButton("Esc: Exit");
    toolTipPane.add(tip1);
    JLabel tip2 = new JLabel("F1: About");
    toolTipPane.add(tip2);
}
```

Comment: by using [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), you would need to override fill, anchor, weightx and weighty (`gbc.weightx = gbc.weighty = 50;`), gridx / gridy (depends of the orientations)

Comment: Hello @mKorbel, thank you for your comment, I have edited my question to include my code, could you show me how I can implement a GridBagLayout in it?

Comment: [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20114198/714968)

Comment: This, in my opinion, is probably a good candidate for a horizontal `JSplitPane`. If so, it might be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61177626/how-to-resize-jtextarea-to-fit-percentage-of-jframe) which I encoutered (and answered) last year. You can start the application with a default width distribution (as a percentage) and then let the user freely move the divider wherever they want, if they want.